# window.location.href redirection not working with # in the url

Tags: javascript, location

why is window.loaction.href not reloading the page if url contains "#".
`window.location.href = window.location.href` in console will reload the page but `window.location.href = window.location.href + "#abc"` will just replace the url without relaoding.

Comment: why you reload page like this? when you have an another separate way to achieve this?

Comment: location.href will not reload the page until it recognises any url change and #param doesn't seem to qualify as a change.adding "?param" seems to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`window.location.href = window.location.href` will not reload the page if there's an anchor (`#`) in the URL, it has the same behavior as a `<a href="#abc>` tag.

Also `window.open(window.location.href + "#abc","_self")` wont refresh the page.

And also this wont work :

```
window.location.href = window.location.href + "#rr";
window.reload();
```

Also `window.location.replace( window.location.href + "#abc");` not gonna work either.

So apparently this is the standard behavior as in `<a href="#abc#>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

for reloading the page in javascript you can simply use

```
window.location.reload()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to navigate to the anchor on the same page you can use

```
window.location.hash = "#abc";
```